# Несколько вопросов про blazor server side

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

Начал изучать blazor (SERVER SIDE(!)) и столкнулся с не понимаем и невозможностью найти ответы на свои вопросы в гугле.

1. Как сделать так, чтобы при заходе на сайт сразу перенаправляло на страницу авторизации, т.е. все страницы сайты были доступны только авторизованному пользователю;
2. Можно ли перенести страницы в библиотеки? Попытался перенести страницу авторизации в отдельную библиотеку в папку Pages, но приложение упорно не видит эту страницу. Выдает только "Sorry, there's nothing at this address.";

Возможно, частичный ответ на первый вопрос у меня есть из гугла, но я не уверен, что он правильный, прикладываю:
Добавил атрибут авторизации в _Imports.razor:

```
@attribute [Authorize]
```

В App.razor поменял структуру на :

```html
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="@true">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <RedirectToLogin/>
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

где RedirectToLogin - компонент razor, лежащий отдельно в другой библиотеке (он работает и всё прекрасно перенаправляет, но страницу /login он не видит):

```
@inject NavigationManager navManager

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        navManager.NavigateTo("login");
    }
}
```

Где страница /login (находится в другой библиотеке по пути: MySite.SecondLib/Pages/Login.razor):

```
@page "/login"

<h1>LOGIN PAGE</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я использую blazor-wasm, но думаю и на server-side все нижесказанное будет работать.

Ответ на 1й вопрос.

1. Удалите @attribute [Authorize] из imports
2. В компоненте RedirectToLogin вызывайте navManager.NavigateTo("login"); не из OnInitialized, а в OnAfterRender. На ServerSide не тестил это, но на WASM словите null.
3. Вам нужно объявить свою реализацию класса AuthenticationStateProvider и переопределить его метод GetAuthenticationStateAsync, который каждый раз будет вызываться для проверки аутентификации пользователя. Также, эту реализацию нужно внедрить в наш контейнер.

```
services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, YourStateProvider>();
```

Короткая версия моего переопределения:

```
public class YourStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    //Мой сервис для идентификации, аутентификации, авторизации
    private readonly ISecurityService _securityService;

    public YourStateProvider(ISecurityService securityService)
    {
        _securityService = securityService;
    }

    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        //Проверяю, если уже в памяти содержится JWT
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_securityService.AccessToken))
        {
            return GetAuthState();
        }

        try
        {
            //Иначе пытаюсь обновить его. New - вызов cqrs-команды
            await _securityService.RefreshTokensAsync(new());
            return GetAuthState();
        }
        catch
        {
            //Возвращаю анонимного пользователя
            return GetAnonymousState();
        }
    }

    #region Private methods

    private AuthenticationState GetAnonymousState()
    {
        var anonymousIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity();
        var anonymousPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(anonymousIdentity);
        return new AuthenticationState(anonymousPrincipal);
    }

    private AuthenticationState GetAuthState()
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(_securityService.Claims, "jwtAuthType");
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        return new AuthenticationState(principal);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Но в моем реальном коде более сложная логика. Вам, скорее всего, можно создать еще один публичный метод, который вы будете вызывать после успешной авторизации, например, из той же страницы входа. Примерный листинг:

```
public class LoginViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly ISecurityService _securityService;
    private readonly YourStateProvider _stateProvider;
    private readonly NavigationManager _navigationManager;

    public LoginViewModel(
        ISecurityService securityService,
        AuthenticationStateProvider authStateProviderб
        NavigationManager navigationManager)
    {
        _securityService = securityService;
        _stateProvider = (YourStateProvider)authStateProvider;
        _navigationManager = navigationManager;
    }

    private async Task LoginExecuteAsync()
    {
        await _securityService.LoginAsync("Отправляем запрос на авторизацию login/pass");
        _stateProvider.NotifyStateChanged();//Уведомляем наш StateProvider о том, что вы вошли
        _navigationManager.NavigateTo("/"); //Редирект в корень
    }
}
```

Полезные ссылки:

1. [Раз](https://youtu.be/wPs39ZrEPQE)
2. [Два](https://youtu.be/BmAnSNfFGsc)

А страницы в библиотеки не переносил. В отдельной библиотеке у меня лежат сервисы, ресурсы, api и прочее-прочее. В клиенте(wasm) это все подключаю, разместил пару компонентов и 90% файлов - view, view.cs + viewmodel

Comment: Ссылки полезные, странно, что мне не показались во время гуглежа, благодарю, буду изучать.